# NaN Custom Error Message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios

I have tried the `isNaN(x)` method shown in a different thread, but trying it just doesn't return anything.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="NKit.js"></script>
<meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes" />



<style>
body
{
background-color:LightGray;
}
h1
{
color:Navy;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
}

h3
{
color:Navy;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
}
h5
{
color:CornflowerBlue;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
}

p
{
font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
color:CadetBlue;
}

</style>



</head>
<body>

<center>

<h1> The Snotor Test Calc </h1> 





        <h3> Enter two numbers below. The blank field will be worked out for you. The algorithm is: 'a + b = c'; Therefore 'c - a = b', and 'c - b = a'. </h3>

        <button type="button" onclick="funca()">A</button> <br> <input id="ai" type="text"> <br> <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="funcb()">B</button> <br> <input id="bi" type="text"> <br> <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="funcc()">C</button> <br> <input id="ci" type="text"> <br> <br>





                    <script>
                        function funca()
                        {
                            //Get the value of input fields
                            var av = document.getElementById("ai");
                            var bv = document.getElementById("bi").value;
                            var cv = document.getElementById("ci").value;

                           if (isNaN(parseFloat(cv))==true||isNaN(parseFloat(bv))==true){
                                av.value = cv-bv;

                           else {
                                av.value="Input Error!";






                        }


                    </script>

                    <script>
                        function funcb()
                        {
                            //Get the value of input fields
                            var av = document.getElementById("ai").value;
                            var bv = document.getElementById("bi");
                            var cv = document.getElementById("ci").value;

                            bv.value = parseFloat(cv)-parseFloat(av);








                        }


                    </script>

                    <script>
                        function funcc()
                        {
                            //Get the value of input fields
                            var av = document.getElementById("ai").value;
                            var bv = document.getElementById("bi").value;
                            var cv = document.getElementById("ci");

                            cv.value = parseFloat(av)+parseFloat(bv);










                        }


                    </script>

                    <h1> Logo Here... </h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Basically, the Javascript after the buttons is designed so that the input boxes do not get filled with `NaN` when one of the other inputs is invalid.

Note: This has only been done on `funca` for button 'a'. 'a' doesn't work at all, whether or not the inputs 'b' and 'c' are invalid. Yet 'b' and 'c' work perfectly (if error in one of the other inputs, it shows `NaN` though).

This, after inserting a custom NaN Error, will be put into PhoneGap and sent of to Apple.

NB: The algorithm will then be changed to a financial algorithm...

Comment: It's `isNaN`, not `isNan`. Is it just a type, or you indeed wrote it like this in your code?

Comment: @raina77ow Oh dear...

Comment: @raina77ow No, I changed it, still doesn't work; I'll update code.

Comment: You know it means "Is_Not_a_Number", so if it's true, it's not a number, and subtracting something that is not a number from something that is not a number works rather poorly. Try checking it it's false instead, as that would mean it actually is a number.

Comment: And running it through parseFloat makes no sense if it's not a number ?

Comment: Try logging `isNaN( parseFloat('holy crap') )` and you'll get `true`, and `holy crap - holy crap` equals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that when the numbers are not a number then you will calculate it. Check this updated javascript.

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/N2mm4/2/

Here is the updated javascript:

```
function funca()
{
    //Get the value of input fields
    var av = document.getElementById("ai");
    var bv = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bi").value);
    var cv = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ci").value);

    if (!isNaN(cv) && !isNaN(bv)){
        ai.value = cv-bv;
    }
    else {
        ai.value="Input Error!";

    }
}   
function funcb()
{
    //Get the value of input fields
    var av = document.getElementById("ai").value;
    var bv = document.getElementById("bi");
    var cv = document.getElementById("ci").value;

    bv.value = parseFloat(cv)-parseFloat(av);

}

function funcc()
{
    //Get the value of input fields
    var av = document.getElementById("ai").value;
    var bv = document.getElementById("bi").value;
    var cv = document.getElementById("ci");

    cv.value = parseFloat(av)+parseFloat(bv);            
}
```